# Laptops unable to access NAS shared folders over 2.4GHz wifi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, nas

My home Internet connection was upgraded to optical fibre last year, with an ISP-supplied Aztech FG7003GRV(AC) wireless router. Ever since operating on this router, my laptops which operate on the 2.4GHz band (don't have one sensitive to 5GHz) are no longer able to access the shared folders on my Synology DS413 NAS.

Be it Windows 7 or Windows 8.1, Windows Explorer goes into that stalled loading mode in any attempt to access any shared folder (e.g. \DS413\video) However, accessing the NAS HTTP web interface is perfectly fine.

These computers can totally access each other's network shares, as well other cabled computers. If a laptop is to access the NAS, it must do so by connecting an Ethernet cable.

Since raw TCP/IP communication over the wifi network is fine (pingable, accessible over HTTP), I believe there is something about SMB on port 445 that is going wrong when transported over the wifi network. The problem is, I do not know what that is. How should I further troubleshoot and get to the bottom of this faulty communication line?

Comment: Have you tried using the IP address for accessing the NAS shares instead? e.g. `\\192.168.x.xx\video`

Comment: @James that would suggest a name resolution problem which is not the case, because the network connection is already established. TCP    192.168.1.107:3447     192.168.1.13:445       ESTABLISHED

Comment: Have you tried updating the router's firmware? There doesn't seem to be any downloads on the Aztech site, but maybe the router's administration interface has an option to check for firmware updates? Also try disabling QoS to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: There's only a pane to upload an _existing_ firmware file; which has to be supplied by the ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why, upon learning the admin credentials to get into the advanced configuration pages of the router, I come across the culprit.

*Poorly configured Quality of Service.*

Once I disable QoS totally, my wireless laptops could readily access the share folders.